JMeter load testing web application-Thread Groups, Controllers, and Timers Selection?
I am assigned to load test a application using jmeter
I have captured all the http request there are around 550 http request and around 10 modules
I need to perform load test
I need help with following
1-  What type of thread groups and controller  should I use , currently all request are in simple controller ?
2-  What type of timers should I use ? application has 2 types of users of which I type of user only needs to be load tested ?
3-  Do I need to use open workload model?
4-  What kind of graph should I use to report ?


What type of thread groups and controller should I use - use the Thread Group(s) which provide the most easily configurable options of controlling ramp-up, ramp-down, time to hold the load, etc. "Normal" Thread Group should be ok, Ultimate Thread Group provides easy visual way to configure the above settings. With regards to Controllers - Simple Controller does nothing, you might want to put the requests which represent a business or logical "transaction" under the Transaction Controller which measures cumulative execution time of its children
What type of timers should I use  - in the majority of cases Constant Timer is a good option. It should represent "think time", the time required for the user to read the content or type something or click a button, you need to simulate realistic delays
Do I need to use open workload model? - it depends on what load pattern you need to simulate, you need to mimic real life usage of the web application by users, if there are spikes or times of higher/lesser load your workload model should reflect this
What kind of graph should I use to report  - if you don't have any specific NFR/SLA to measure you can use default charts and tables provided by HTML Reporting Dashboard

